# Cannot deploy spring boot application to another vm

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-data

I have developed a spring boot application and it is running fine in my local system. Now, I would like to host in one of the windows vm, so that others can test the application. I tried generating the jar as well as war of the same and deployed it in a tomcat server as we do for other spring applications. But, I am getting Error 404. How do I deploy it? I am new to spring boot.

Please help.

Thanks,
Poorna.

Answer (score 1):

You just follow the steps given below,

- First you just run the clean package, the it will generate jar/war file to your target folder.
- After that export you project using File->Export.
- Then you just deploy the exported war file to your tomcat server path.
- Restart the tomcat server.

Comment: I tried all these. None of them works for me. This is what is shown in catalina.out file.

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.altair.dlc.controller.Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/application.properties]